# mailboxer gem - find message sender

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, messaging, mailboxer

I am having the hardest time with the mailboxes gem.  I have gotten it working in that I can send and receive messages, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to display them.  i want to display the inbox in table organized like this:

```
message sender | message subject | message sent date
```

I have been working for hours to try and figure out how to access the sender of the message in the receivers inbox, but I can't figure it out.  I've tried looping through conversations, receipts, notifications, etc and I still cannot figure out what to do.  I can't use:

```
#user wants to retrieve all his conversations
user.mailbox.conversations

#user wants to retrieve his inbox
user.mailbox.inbox

#user wants to retrieve his sent conversations
user.mailbox.sentbox
```

because there is no way to organize how the messages are displayed using those methods (at least as far as I know).  How can I loop through the messages and find the message sender for each message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Mailboxer::Message` is a `Mailboxer::Notification`

And you can have the notification's sender: `message.sender`

A `Mailboxer::Conversation` is a collection of messages.

You can get the `participants`, even the `originator` (plus many other) from it.

Is it clearer?

Comment: Thank you.  That clears  up some things actually.  I was able to get my inbox to work, but now I'm having even more trouble with the sent box.  Would you mind taking a look at this question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417883/how-to-access-recipient-on-sent-messages-page-with-mailboxer