# How to access recipient on sent messages page with mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, messaging, mailboxer

I am using the mailboxer gem to send messages within my ruby on rails app.  The gem is working.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to access the recipient on the sent messages page.  On the sent messages page, I am trying to loop through sent messages, and access the recipient of the sent messages and display that person to the user.

On the regular inbox page, I used the following:

```
<% all_mail = current_user.mailbox.inbox %>
<% all_mail.each do |letter| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= letter.messages.last.sender.email %></td>
        <td><%= letter.messages.last.subject %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to make a similar look for the sent messages page, but I can't figure out how to do it(specifically access the email of the recipient).

I can't use:

```
#user wants to retrieve all his conversations
user.mailbox.conversations

#user wants to retrieve his inbox
user.mailbox.inbox

#user wants to retrieve his sent conversations
user.mailbox.sentbox
```

because there is no way to organize how the messages are displayed using those methods (at least as far as I know). How can I loop through the messages and find the message recipient for each message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the participants in conversations (you call it letters).

Just filter the current user and you'll be good.

```
conversation = user.mailbox.sentbox.first
filtered_participants = conversation.participants.reject do |u| 
  u.id == current_user.id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Each message has recipients, which is a list. Assuming that your conversations are just between two users you can grab for the first list's element:

```
<% conversation.messages.each do |message| %>
  <%= message.recipients.first.email %>, <%= message.body %>
<% end %>
```